# Looping moving background objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

I am testing a background-loop animation where there will be to images both 1024x768 pixels in dimension, move leftwards, go offscreen, then jump back to the other side, and repeat.

I was able to do this by creating a constant speed for both background image to move (successful), and then I tried the following code to make it jump, but there was a problem:

```
    if((background.center.x) < -511){
        background.center = CGPointMake(1536, background.center.y);
    }

    if((background2.center.x) < -511){
        background2.center = CGPointMake(1536, background2.center.y);
    }
```

Somehow this is not working the way I expected. It leaves a few pixels of gap every time, and I am confused why. Does anyone know what's causing this to happen and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: iOS and the constant speed variable is 10

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have forgotten to take into account the distance moved. The greater than expression might have been triggered because you moved to far. I guess your movement is larger than 1 pixel/frame.

I am not sure what kind of values that are feeding your movement but I think to take into account the movement you should do something like...

```
 if ((background.center.x) < -511){
    CGFloat dist = background.center.x + 512;
    background.center = CGPointMake(1536+dist, background.center.y);
 }

 if ((background2.center.x) < -511){
    CGFloat dist = background2.center.x + 512;
    background2.center = CGPointMake(1536+dist, background2.center.y);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have the two images move (sort of) independently, I would keep track of a single `backgroundPosition` variable and then constantly update the position of both images relative to that one position. This should keep everything nice and tidy:

```
CGFloat const backgroundWidth = 1024;
CGFloat const backgroundSpeed = 2;

- (void)animateBackground {
    backgroundPosition -= backgroundSpeed;
    if (backgroundPosition < 0) {
        backgroundPosition += backgroundWidth;
    }
    background1.center.x = backgroundPosition - backgroundWidth/2;
    background2.center.x = backgroundPosition + backgroundWidth/2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i found a different solution based on your answer...

I found out this issue was caused by the displacement of pixels per frame, since my constant is 10, i subtracted 10 from 512, which is the half of 1024, so that it will move to the other side 10px before it touches the other side since that 10px will disappear after another frame, which solved the problem.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: We're all about solutions here. Glad to hear that you worked it out! `:)`